# Complex type in POCO produces NullReferenceException in DetectChanges/SaveChanges

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I have a strange behaviour when trying to save an entity in EF 4.0.

Just consider a simple complex type with one String-Property. Then I have an entity POCO-Class (actually an STE, but that's not the point here), that contains several complex properties of this complex type.

Then the behavior can be shown with following code:

```
  var object = context.Records.Where(p => p.ID = requestedID).First();  // works
  object.ComplexProp1 = new ComplexTypeA(...);

  context.DetectChanges();  // success
  context.DetectChanges(); // NullReferenceException
```

This code is just to show the error. It actually happened when I called SaveChanges(), what calls DetectChanges() internally, so I used this code to reproduce.
After a lot of debugging EF code I found, that inside of EntityEntry.FindOriginalValue() method, the second time there is no original value found and this causes the exception elsewhere.
This doesn't happen if:

1. I don't set the complex property to a new instance, but set the property of the complex type itself instead (like: object.ComplexProp1.Value = "yes")
2. I use the STE way. Obtain the object from context 1, apply the changes into context 2 and save it there.

But preserving always the complex type instance is no option, nor the STE variant is.
I have no idea if this is a kind of bug or what I may change to prevent this error. Does anyone have at least a hunch what's happening there? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try it on EF5, I vaguely remember an issue with complex types and calling DetectChanges twice that was fixed in EF5? Also what can you show a stack trace?

Comment: So, if I understand this right, it sounds as this is sort of a bug? Unfortunately EF5 is no option, for now. But I'll eventually try this.